# Missing "Copy to Output Direcotry" option for files in "Solution Items" folder

Tags: visual-studio

I'm using Visual Studio 2022.

There is no **Copy to Output Direcotry** for files in **Solution Items** folder. But, this option does exist for files within a project.

Is there a way to make this happen instead of adding those files to a project or adding "xcopy..." to "Post-build event" for each project's page property?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Solution items belong to a solution, and the solution doesn't have any output directory. If you have 50 projects in your solution, where would you expect such items to be copied?

Comment: I would add the file to each project where it's needed, but with Add - Existing item - Add as link. This way you will have just one physical file and when you edit it, the changes will be automatically visible in all affected projects.